# PHP MySQL Data To AngularJS

Tags: mysql, ajax, angularjs

I am using this code to pull data from a MySQL.

```
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'api.php',     
  data: "",
  dataType: 'json',    
  success: function(data)
  {
    var id = data[0]; 
    var icon = data[1];
    var english = data[2];
    var british = data[3];
    $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> icon: </b>"+icon+"<b> english: </b>"+english+"<b> british: </b>"+british); //Set output element html
  }
```

And it outputs this correctly but my questions is how would put this data into the below.

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        english: '<First Row english>',
        british: '<First Row british>',
        image: '<First Row icon>'
    },
    {
        english: '<Second Row english>',
        british: '<Second Row british>',
        image: '<Second Row icon>'
    }
      //So on and so forth for all the records in the DB. 
   ]
```

This is from api.php not sure if this needs to be returned a certain way?

```
<?php 
require_once 'db.php'; // The mysql database connection script
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName") or die(mysql_error());

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
 $arr[] = $obj;
}

echo $json_response = json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
  require_once 'db.php'; // The mysql database connection script
  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName") or die(mysql_error());
  $arr[];
  while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
      array_push($arr, $obj);
  }

  echo $json_response = json_encode($arr);

 ?>
```

JS

```
 $http.get('api.php').success(function(data) {
     $scope.items = data;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it isn't quite working yet. I have added the code from api.php incase i am returning it wrong?

Comment: Then instead of numbers in data[] use columns name ex:  english : data['english'],

Comment: Try new code, of course $http.get is in an angular controller